# Ajax form POST returns a 403 error with a string in field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mime, contenttype

I have a contact form. When sending it I use AJAX to send a mail and reply to the user.
To get the form data I use `var form = $('#form').serialize();`

```
$('#form').click(function(e){
    $('#form_msg').hide().html('');

    var form = $('#form').serialize();
    form += '&lingua='+lingua;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'contatti.php',
        cache: false,
        data: form,
        success: function(result){
            $('#form').html(result);
        },
        error: function(data){
            $('#form_msg').html(data.responseText).show();
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The form has 2 `input[type=text]` and a `textarea`.

I noticed that when I post something like

```
Content-Type%3A+text%2Fhtml
```

on the `textarea` the server returns a `403 error` and after a few sends it crash.

Why? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is the variable lingua? Can't you add it to a hidden input field in the form and serialize instead?

Comment: The `lingua` variable is the language. This variable is used by `.htaccess` to tell a global PHP class which language the user is working with.